# How to access UIAlertAction title property in Swift?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController with multiple UIAlertActions. I am wanting to access the UIAlertAction title property of the selected action.

```
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Filter", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CIBumpDistortion", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CIGaussianBlur", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CIPixellate", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CISepiaTone", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CITwirlDistortion", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CIUnsharpMask", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CIVignette", style: .default, handler: setFilter))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
```

Accessing the ac.title property only access the AlertController title property.

Looking into the Apple documentation, it looks like I may need to use something like

```
var title: String? { get }
```

However I'm not familiar on how to use this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in the documentation shows you how the `title` property is *declared*, not how you would refer to it in your code (though it can give some insights).

Since it is a property, you can access it via the dot notation `.title` if you have an instance of `UIAlertAction`. Luckily, you do have access to the selected instance of `UIAlertAction`: the parameter passed to the `handler` function!

In the handler of the alert action, i.e. `setFilter`, you can access its parameter's `.title`. This will be the selected action's title.

```
func setFilter(_ action: UIAlertAction) {
    let selectedActionTitle = action.title
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was kind of unclear to me, even as someone fairly fluent in Swift. Below is a simple example of how to easily structure a UIAlertController with an action that returns the title value of the action:

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: .default, handler: { [self] action in
        let actionTitle = action.title
}))
```